# Workflow needed for colaborative video with multiple contributors submitting to one person

Tags: workflow

A friend of mine has a partner who is refusing to have a party for a major birthday, and what she wants to do instead is gather short videos of birthday greetings from all the friends of her partner, and possibly edit them together - around 30 people - and then present the video on her partner's birthday. The majority of the friends are non-video savvy, and they would be shooting a clip on their smartphones. The message and greeting is far more important than the quality.

She thought she could ask for the videos by email. However, a 3-4 minute clip is going to come in around 0.5 GB, so she would be asking for 15GB of video by email, which is not practical. And non-savvy people will have trouble emailing anyway (won't understand things like need for reliable, good internet connection, how long it will take, etc.).

So I'm wondering about a cloud based solution - an easy way for each person to upload to the account of my friend, where she can collate and edit.

I don't think YouTube or similar fit the bill. YouTube's model is that you upload to your own account. And seeing as its now so tightly linked to Google+, creating a one-off account for the purpose would be difficult, and asking the friends to upload to that one account (by sharing credentials) would interfere with any of them who already have accounts, and then afterwards would leave 'debris' account settings that would soon be forgotten, and then cause confusion if later discovered.

What would be great would be a kind of video drop box, that doesn't require contributors to go through an arduous sign up process, and could be easily accessed through a phone app.

The friends just need to be able to make the video and have an easy way to upload it. Complicated installs, setup and signups is beginning to ask too much.

http://www.wevideo.com looked as if it might help, but possibly requires everyone to have an account.

Very grateful if any of you know of an inexpensive cloud product/service that would ease this task which you can recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you check out [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com/dropbox/). The site is meant to allow users to create custom forms to that anonymous people can upload content to that users Public Dropbox folder.

You could easily create a form where people could write a message and then upload the video they took to the employees public Dropbox folder who is doing all of the video editing.

Google Drive has a similar feature to JotForm, but you just create the form inside of Google Docs instead of through an external API. [Here is the link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/) with instructions on how it's done.